# Piping ppm files to ffmpeg to create movie in c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, ffmpeg

I want to create a movie of a zoom on the Mandelbrot set.  To do this I want to create image data in the ppm format and then pipe it into ffmpeg using popen.  The following command works if I first save the ppm to my disc and then run ffmpeg through the terminal.

```
ffmpeg -i out.ppm -r 1/5 out.mp4
```

Here is what I am trying to do in code.

```
FILE* p = popen("ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin -r 1/5 out.mp4", "w");
ppm_pipe(p, pix_buffers[0], w, h);
fclose(p);
...
void ppm_pipe(FILE* f, unsigned char* pix, int w, int h)
{
    assert(fprintf(f, "P6 %d %d 255\n", w, h) > 0);
    size_t sz = 3 * (size_t)w * (size_t)h;
    assert(fwrite(pix, 1, sz, f) == sz);
}
```

I get the following error message.

```
ffmpeg version 2.5.8-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.15.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-gnutls --enable-openal --enable-libopencv --enable-librtmp --enable-libx265
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
/dev/stdin: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: according to [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe), you should try `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 ...`

Comment: Still gives the same error.

Comment: shouldn't the ppm files be in ascii? Your fwrite is going to write binary file?

Comment: Does it make a difference.  I am on linux so I think it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need a newline, '\n', between the PPM header sections, i.e. the P6 and the width/length, and the width/length and the max value. So the format string should be:

```
"P6\n%d %d\n255\n"
```